# 301 Redirect in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, http-status-code-301

I have an Multiculture MVC2 website.
Actually my home page can be accessed with the following paths:

```
http://mydomain.com
http://mydomain.com/
http://mydomain.com/en
http://mydomain.com/en/
http://mydomain.com/en/home
http://mydomain.com/en/home/
```

What I want is that all the above paths make a 301 redirect to the following:

```
http://mydomain.com/en
```

so that I don't have to share pagerank between different urls.

Note that the `en` string is dynamic and sets the culture for the website.

I'm new in Asp.Net MVC, someone could post some code to do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom action result. See this thread: http://forums.asp.net/p/1337938/2700733.aspx

Answer (score 2):

something like this

```
public class PermanentRedirectResult : ViewResult
{
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public PermanentRedirectResult(string url)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
            throw new ArgumentException("url is null or empty", url);
        this.Url = url;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
      if (context == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
      context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 301;
      context.HttpContext.Response.RedirectLocation = Url;
      context.HttpContext.Response.End();
    }
}
```

and call it with this

> return new
>   PermanentRedirectResult("/myurl");

Comment: To downvoter? Why downvote this answer 2yrs after it was posted, at the very least you could do is provide a comment? Also remember this is MVC version 2!